# Offline Access to StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, data-dump, offline

I'm going to start studying/developing at my local [university's](http://www.dal.ca/) library, but since I'm not a student I won't have access to their wireless network. Therefore, I won't be able to access StackOverflow if I have a question.

I was wondering if anyone had used the data dumps to make a somewhat usable offline copy of the site, so that I'll at least have access to the existing SO knowledge. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723017/offline-documentation-for-various-programming-languages) provides links to the various APIs/documentation, but I think the benefits of having SO as well should be obvious to anyone obsessed enough to be here on meta.

If I can't find anything, I'll likely write something to migrate the XML dumps into MySQL and whip something up to get at least a passable copy.

Thanks for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and comments, I think you're going to be in stuck imprting the data dump to a mySQL database and querying. :(

Comment: Pretty much my thoughts. I'll be sure to post something when I'm done.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [data dump of SO](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/). It gets updated about every month.

Alternatively I'd highly suggest investing in your own wireless connection if that's an option. I don't know where you live but 3G wireless broadband is pretty cheap these days. Some netbooks/laptops have 3G built in. Alternatively it's just a USB key.

You could even use the browser on your phone depending on what you have but frankly I'd rather have a netbook (at least) for that kind of thing.

Comment: "I was wondering if anyone had used the data dumps to make a somewhat usable offline copy of the site"

Comment: Not sure but personally I'd spend the $10/month on your own connection (if thats an option).

Comment: My question already references the data dumps. I was just hoping there would be something a little more user-friendly than a > 1GB XML file that chokes my laptop. As far the "buy your own" suggestion, I'm being pretty frugal these days due to being unemployed. Also, I sort of *like* not having internet at the library, since I won't check my email/reddit/facebook/etc every 5 minutes.

Comment: $10 a month? Damn, that does sound worth it if it's true. I'm in Canada, and I know we have a bit of a reputation for crappy wireless internet up here. Definitely looking into just for the potential that it really is that cheap.

Comment: Also 3G isn't that cheap in most places. Where I live its about $50 for enough bandwidth to load the google homepage a few times.

Comment: @AgentConundrum, also in Canada. Yet to see any solutions nearly that cheap ;p

Comment: Bell Mobility and Rogers Wireless seem to have 1G/month 3G wireless for $30/month. Ok, slightly more than $10 but even 1G is a lot of browsing. I was using 3G at one work site and did maybe 50MB/day.

Comment: @Ian: Just checked Rogers' site. It's $25/mo for 500MB transfer and $0.03/MB after that, plus a $6.95 system access fee (which I may or may not already be paying through my cell phone, depending on if Rogers considers them separate).  That's for one of those USB sticks.

Comment: Also interesting to note that Halifax has better coverage than I would have had back home in Kingston, ON. I just assumed that Atlantic Canada would be the land that time forgot.

Comment: Yes I have the 500MB/month on my phone, but 500MB isn't that much data these days TBH. With the same price in the states you could probably get at least 5GB,  if not unlimited.

Comment: I have 3G/month as part of my phone plan (for $39/month including $350 of calls) and I never even got close to 3G using it Mon-Fri. It depends if you just want to browse the Web or sit there and watch Youtube though.

Comment: Oh and I should point out that you may have a price difference between getting a separate 3G service vs getting 3G data on your phone service (assuming you have one) and then tethering the phone to a laptop, which is what I did.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an application [StackDump](https://stackapps.com/questions/3610/stackdump-an-offline-browser-for-stackexchange-sites) for viewing StackOverflow and other StackExchange sites offline.

StackOverflow is also available in [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) (OSX only).