# Application to read Stack Overflow off-line

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I'm now going on vacation, and I won't be having Internet connection there. I was thinking it would be a good time to browse through the Stack Overflow data dump. However, it's all in XML and I'd have to write a client to make it readable. Is there any existing client?

Comment: sounds like a good vacation project...

Comment: Check http://stackapps.com.

Comment: A meta question, if I have ever seen one.

Comment: Use your vacation to write a simple [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) web application that runs locally and uses the XML files as a DB. Use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for a fast XML parser. If you know those technologies, it shouldn't take more than an hour to get something quite usable up.

Comment: Last summer holiday I used StackPrinter to save in pdf files around fifty [top-voted](http://www.stackprinter.com/topvoted) Stack Overflow questions to read them on my ereader; it worked really good.

Comment: In case it gets good answers over there, see [the equivalent question on stackapps](http://stackapps.com/questions/1867/application-to-read-stackoverflow-off-line).

Comment: no, it sounds like something very boring to write(thats why they call it gui) and I bet its already written and I just cant find it.

Comment: I dont't think that *boring* is a good reason to post the same question 3 times :-(

Comment: I post it so much, because many times my questions are just getting closed, so I hoped at least one will survive.

Comment: Harden up and be a true geek! Import it into a database and then query it to find the questions and answers, and maybe deluxe-ify your query so that it sorts the answers by number of upvotes.

Comment: Ai, if closing questions has taught you to post new questions multiple times, then we're doing something wrong. :-( On the other hand: every close message links to the FAQ, doesn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Offline Access to StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19841/offline-access-to-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is similar to [Stack Overflow portable edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20823/stack-overflow-portable-edition) which is a project I started a while ago. I haven't done much with the original code (and the site is offline at the moment).

However, recently I've been experimenting with creating an e-book for the Kindle (in Mobipocket format). I may be working on this over the holiday break.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is:

https://launchpad.net/aubrowser

Don't be fooled, although it is named "AskUbuntu Browser", it'll work on any of the Stack Exchange sites.

[image]

Comment: Needs more drop shadows.

Comment: @Jon: Fair enough... it uses WebKit, so that's a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

We have created a tool ‘StackedOff’ which is an offline StackExchange indexer and search engine.

You can find it at: [At the StackedOff github page](https://github.com/tools4j/stacked-off)

Some screenshots:

**Search:**

[image: Search]

**Question view**

[image: Question view]

**Selecting a site to index:**

[image: Selecting a site to index]

Answer (score 3):

Just browse through the applications at [StackApps.com](https://stackapps.com) for something like:

[Stack Overflow offline PDF question reader](https://stackapps.com/questions/2652/stack-overflow-offline-pdf-question-reader)

Comment: Oh, it looks like you just did.

Answer (score 1):

[Dash.app](https://kapeli.com/dash) (OSX) does this very well, too; it allows subscription to tags you select. Good for conferences.

[image]